# Execution time for Core JavaScript vs jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

If my purpose is served by core JavaScript only, should I use jQuery?

I mean if I use those libraries, will the application become slower or remain same?

If anyone have any reference, can you please share with me?

Comment: https://medium.com/@mattburgess/all-javascript-frameworks-are-terrible-e68d8865183e

Comment: If jquery is too heavy for you, check out [zepto](http://zeptojs.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: It really depends on what you are planning to do.

For example: A simple static webpage may not need angular or even jQuery for that matter.
A web application on the other hand can really benefit from using libraries/frameworks such as Angular and React.

A good rule of thumb is to use only what you need, not bloat up your project with libraries and dependencies just because.
You can achieve really good page speeds with or without frameworks, a good start is googling around and see what you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Sure

Actually AngularJS is also use jQuery Dom selection code for angular.element.
Its called jqlite.

Also for most of CSS framework like bootstrap, foundation jQuery is also required because most of utility is still built with jQuery.
AngularJS is also very powerful but sometimes its dependent on jQuery.

So you can use both of it on a single page no worries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes using jquery or angular means additional code that needs to be executed, and that means a measurable difference in execution time, although usually not a noticeable time difference.

**But that's the wrong question to ask**

*I don't know what application you have in mind, and how experienced you are, so ...*

- both jquery and angular provide a lot of stuff which may speed up your development time tremendously.
- can you write code that contains fewer bugs, memory leaks, attack-vectors, etc. than these frameworks, which have already been used/tested thousands of times in production?
- Are you sure you can write code that is more performant than these libs? Especially from jquery I know, that there are some pretty ugly corners, but can you do it better? I don't know your skill level.
- browser compatibility: how skilled are you on that topic?
- and at last, **why reinvent the wheel?**

Oh, and about performance in web-pages. A few years ago there was a statistic going around about performance, with the general summary:

- js usually uses only about 15% of the performance/runtime.
- something around 60-80% of the runtime is used to render the page
- if you want to *"improve the performance"* of your JS, don't micro-optimize stuff, but check where you trigger render-cycles that can be avoided.